# Empty array output from the $lookup aggregation operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get the most popular recipes.

I have 2 relevant collections: recipes and favoriterecipes.

Things to consider: I've double checked collections names and ids.

In the db itself the _recipe field in favoriterecipes is type string and in recipes it is an ObjectId. (maybe a type conversion is required? even though I didn't see such thing in "lookup" examples).

favoriteRecipe.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Recipe = require("./recipe");
const User = require("./user");

const FavoritesRecipesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _recipe: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Recipe },
  _user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("FavoriteRecipe", FavoritesRecipesSchema);
```

recipe.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./user");

const RecipeScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  ingredients: [String],
  instructions: String,
  image: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  tags: [String],
  _user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Recipe", RecipeScheme);
```

controller.js:

```
exports.popular = async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const popular_recipes = await favoriteRecipe.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$_recipe",
          recipeCount: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
      { $sort: { recipeCount: -1 } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "recipes",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "recipe",
        },
      },
      // { $unwind: "$recipe" },
      // {
      //   $project: {
      //     _id: "$recipe",
      //     recipeCount: 1,
      //   },
      // },
    ]);
    res.json(popular_recipes);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

response output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6053349353b5f5632986b2c2",
        "recipeCount": 3,
        "recipe": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "6053349353b5f5632986b2c3",
        "recipeCount": 2,
        "recipe": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "605603945b4aeb0d2458153e",
        "recipeCount": 1,
        "recipe": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found that I have to convert the id string to an object id. the solution:

```
exports.popular = async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const popular_recipes = await favoriteRecipe.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $toObjectId: "$_recipe" },
          recipeCount: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
      { $sort: { recipeCount: -1 } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "recipes",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "recipe",
        },
      },
      { $unwind: "$recipe" },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: "$recipe",
          recipeCount: 1,
        },
      },
    ]);
    res.json(popular_recipes);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```